# Binding a Directive Controller's method to its parent $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I will explain what exactly I'm trying to do before explaining the issue. I have a Directive which holds a form, and I need to access that form from the parent element (where the Directive is used) when clicking on a submit button to check fi the form is valid.

To do this, I am trying to use `$scope.$parent[$attrs.directiveName] = this;` and then binding some methods to the the Directive such as `this.isValid` which will be exposed and executable in the parent.

This works fine when running locally, but when minifying and building my code (Yeoman angular-fullstack) I will get an error for `aProvider` being unknown which I traced back to a `$scopeProvider` error in the Controller.

I've had similar issues in the past, and my first thought was that I need to specifically say `$inject` for `$scope` so that the name isn't lost. But alas.....no luck.

Is something glaringly obvious that I am doing wrong?

Any help appreciated.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('formDirective', formDirective);

    function formDirective() {
      var directive = {
        templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
          user: '='
        },
        controller: controller
      };

      return directive;

      controller.$inject = ['$scope', '$attrs', 'myService'];
      function controller($scope, $attrs, myService) {
        $scope.myService = myService;

        // Exposes the Directive Controller on the parent Scope with name Directive's name
        $scope.$parent[$attrs.directiveName] = this;

        this.isValid = function() {
          return $scope.myForm.$valid;
        };

        this.setDirty = function() {
          Object.keys($scope.myForm).forEach(function(key) {
            if (!key.match(/\$/)) {
              $scope.myForm[key].$setDirty();
              $scope.myForm[key].$setTouched();
            }
          });

          $scope.myForm.$setDirty();
        };
      }

    }
})();
```

Comment: I would look at changing from a directive to a component https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component. Then use the idea of inputs and outputs to communicate from the parent container and the component. What you are doing is not the the right way to do it.

Comment: Jeez, didn't realize `.component` was added to Angular 1.x Some help on converting this existing logic to a component would be greatly appreciated indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the directive to a component and implement a clear interface.

Parent Container (`parent.html`):

```
<form-component some-input="importantInfo" on-update="someFunction(data)">    
</form-component>
```

Parent controller (`parent.js`):

```
//...

$scope.importantInfo = {data: 'data...'};
$scope.someFunction = function (data) {
   //do stuff with the data 
}

//..
```

`form-component.js`:

```
angular.module('app')
.component('formComponent', {
  template:'<template-etc>',
  controller: Controller,
  controllerAs: 'ctrl',
  bindings: {
    onUpdate: '&',
    someInput: '<'
  }
});

function Controller() {

    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.someFormThing = function (value) {
    ctrl.onUpdate({data: value})
}

}
```

So if an event in your form triggers the function `ctrl.someFormThing(data)`. This can be passed up to the parent by calling `ctrl.onUpdate()`.

Comment: How would you handle a case where you don't want to manually trigger the `onUpdate` call? In my case, I have a form and I need to know from the parent if that form is valid or not. I currently have an `isValid` method which returns `form.$valid`, so using the Component syntax how could I access that from the parent?

Comment: Just to be clear. The parent contains a child directive which contains a form. The parent needs to be informed of the the state of the form when it changes? Or does the parent need to 'request' the state of the form? Either way you should use onUpdate. So you could have a $watch on form.$valid and call onUpdate if it changes. Then in your parent, the function called that is the target changes the parents 'local' state of the form. You know you can have 2 way binding of a property if you want. But it's not advised. Read the component docs.